# Creating a forum with HTML5 local storage

Tags: javascript, html

For a school project I'm trying to create a forum with HTML5 local storage. Here people can create and submit a simple post, but I don't know how to list all the posts underneath on a single page. This is what I have:

```
<form id="createpost" action="forum.html">
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="text" id="age">
    <input type="text" id="topic">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

So on the page  "forum.html" all created posts have to appear. I already know how to set items in the local storage, but I don't know how to display all the posts underneath each other on one page.

I really appreciate it if you could help me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: But how would it be a forum when each user has their own local storage?

Comment: I know, it's a lame assignment from my teacher who happens to call it a forum.. :')

Comment: Check out this example under **The localStorage object** http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp it shows how to print that information. That could give you an idea.

Comment: @EricMartinez don't use w3schools as reference, use MDN instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Let's say for the case of argument that you're storing all of your posts as objects, like this example:

```
localStorage = [
  {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: "20",
    topic: "Being anonymous"
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    age: "20",
    topic: "Finding John"
  },
];
```

(Also, say you're using jquery, and have a div of class 'posts').
You could use some Javascript native function to go through each object, and translate them into a list:

```
localStorage.map(function(forumPost){
  $('.posts').append( "<ul>
                         <li>"forumPost.name"</li>
                         <li>"forumPost.age"</li>
                         <li>"forumPost.topic"</li>
                       </ul>")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you know how to store items:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

How do you store your posts? I would use an array of objects like this:

```
var posts = [{
        topic: 'localstorage forum',
        user: 'John Doe' }, {
        topic: 'another topic',
        user: 'Eleina'
    }];
```

I would store and get data like this:

```
//store
localStorage.setItem("posts", JSON.stringify(posts));

//get
var posts = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("posts") || "[]" );
```

Since it's an array you can then loop through it and create HTML based on it:

```
html = '';

for(var i=0; i<posts.length; i++) {
    html += '<div class="post">';
    html += '<b>' + posts[i].topic + '</b> by ' + posts[i].user;
    html += '</div>';
}

//output the html somehow, with jquery that could be
$("body").append(html);
```

Hope this helps :)